# How can I provide hints to PhpStorm to find my Laravel custom query builder methods?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm

I'm using custom [query builders](https://laravel-beyond-crud.com/) in Laravel like this:

```php
class MyModel extends Model {
 public function newEloquentBuilder($query): MyModelQueryBuilder
    {
        return new MyModelQueryBuilder($query);
    }
}
```

```php
class MyModelQueryBuilder extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder {
  // various query methods...
}
```

Because of Laravel's so-called Facades and use of magic methods, PhpStorm cannot find references to the methods in my custom query builder.

I use the [barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) package to generate hints for my Models, so their methods are findable and hintable.  How can I do the same thing in an easy, maintainable way for my query builder classes?

For example, I'd like to be able to press Command-B while on a query builder method, and get the list of users of that method, for example, as I can with other fully cross-referenced classes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to add the class methods to the model using the [unofficial](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/issues/35) `@mixin` PHPDoc directive. PhpStorm has had support for it [for a few years](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1730) now. A trait is probably the easiest way to do this on multiple models:

```php
/**
 * @mixin MyModelQueryBuilder
 */

trait HasCustomBuilder {

    public function newEloquentBuilder($query): MyModelQueryBuilder
    {
        return new MyModelQueryBuilder($query);
    }
}
```

```php
class MyModel extends Model {
    use HasCustomBuilder;
}
```